# Displaying user input from one gui panel to display on another gui panel

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to find out how I can link a string from another class into another class (sorry if this is said wrong). Anyways I have a login gui and a mainmenu gui, I want the mainmenu gui to display the username of the person who is logged in so I guess the easiest way is to get the string from the user inputting their username from the login gui. Below is my two .java files.

Overall my goal is to get the userinput lets say a username of `Admin`. I want this to be displayed on my mainmenu as a JLabel `Welcome user: Admin`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the username as a parameter to MainMenu's constructor?

In Login:

```
String uname = jtfUsername.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Succesfully Logged in, Welcome user : " + uname);
MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu(uname);
```

In MainMenu:

```
public MainMenu(String uname) {
    //create menu bar
    JMenuBar regMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setTitle("Main Menu");

    //set menu bar to the applet
    setJMenuBar(regMenuBar);
    ...
```

Comment: To extend this answer, you could then create a JLabel like such, `JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Welcome user: " + uname);` to display the username in your MainMenu.java.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class that contains both the panels. Through this class you could exchange information from both panels.

Using a MVC architecture you are holding for information outside the GUI and accessible from all the frames.